# Query all the videos from user device in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, video

I want to make a video player app using flutter and dart but I have no idea how to query all the videos on both Android and IOS. Using Java for native android development, this is possible using
the MediaStore and a Content Resolver to query all media files(video in this case) on device along with whatever property of the media is needed. How can I do the same using Dart in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) dependency to achieve this for both platforms (Android/iOS).

```
final List<AssetPathEntity> paths = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList();
```